# CompoundContributionItem In E4

Tags: eclipse-plugin, e4

I have an implementation of `CompoundContributionItem` that I want to get to work in an pure E4 application. I found some kind of [documentation](https://wiki.eclipse.org/E4/Menus#Main_Menu) for other `IContributionItem`s, but not for this one.

What's the mechanism for implementing `CompoundContributionItem`in E4?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's done via the `@AboutToShow` annotation:

```
public class PluginEnablementContributionItem {

    @AboutToShow
    public void aboutToShow(List<MMenuElement> items) {
        MDirectMenuItem item = MMenuFactory.INSTANCE.createDirectMenuItem();
        item.setLabel("My Menu Item");
        item.setContributorURI("platform:/plugin/org.acme.project");
        item.setContributionURI("bundleclass://org.acme.project/org.acme.project.MyHandler");
        items.add(item);
    }

}
```